# can not import the module deepcopy

Tags: python

i've ran into this wierd error since few days where most of the applications/frameworks/modules will refuse to run , because of of the unavailability of the module deepcopy i can't understand why is that so ?

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/django/http/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from django.utils.datastructures import MultiValueDict, ImmutableList
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/django/utils/datastructures.py", line 3, in <module>
    from django.utils.copycompat import deepcopy
ImportError: cannot import name deepcopy
```

why is that so ? and how it can be fixed ?

Comment: Did you reinstall Django yet?

Comment: Turns out it was a typo, flagged to close. glad you figured it out

Answer (score 15, accepted):

seems like i had another copy.py file in my path that was confusing python .removed it and it worked like a charm .

Comment: Thanks a lot. I had been struggling for quite a while

Answer (score 1):

If think you want to use:

```
from copy import deepcopy
```

I can't import it either. I think it has been removed from Django.